# Error following django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow the django tutorial but I get this error and I can't continue. 
http://dpaste.com/630957/

Can someone help me?
(I'm new with python and django) Thank you so much.

Comment: why don't u try checking what choice and what all attributes it has with dir() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error log:

```
File "/arpa/h/huksy007/Projects/mysite/polls/models.py" in __unicode__
    22.         return self.question
```

Make sure that `self` actually has a property called `question`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put that line on your Choice Model:

```
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

It need to be like that:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

---

EDIT:

Sorry, I was thinking of something else and didn't realize it was this line you should change to your model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.choice
```

You probably have this on your Choice model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question
```

And question its from the Poll model.

Comment: Sorry, got confused by another thing and answered incorrectly.